# ¿Porqué Visual Studio Code no cambia correctamente el tema de colores?

Tags: vscode

Hace tiempo deje de usar VSCode. Recientemente lo abrí y se ve así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este no es el tema que deje instalado, pénse que la extención llamada Ayu se había desconfigurado, por lo que la instale nuevamente, y escogí el tema "Ayu Dark" y ahora luce así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque cambia la apariencía del editor, el color del código y los iconos no se ven como debería. Intente cambiar al tema por defecto, pero no deja de tener los colores mal.

¿Como puedo solucionar esto?

también intente volver a instalar VSCode, elimnando todos sus archivo utilizando el comando

apt-get -purge remove code

sin embargo no funcionó

Comment: Recuerda que estás en un sitio de preguntas y respuestas, por lo tanto, en lugar de editar tu pregunta escribiendo "solución", **ponlo como respuesta** y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Saludos. Si, precisamente estaba buscando como marcar la solución, pensé que se podia desde la misma pregunta. Gracias por recordarme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución:

Utilizó Linux Lite, este tiene una aplicación llamada "Color profiles" y tenía una configuración activada, basto solo con desactivarla y problema resuelto.

[image: Color profile]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]